# How can I retrieve all the groups name from server on parse.com in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am facing a big problem in parse api. I am able to create new group on server as well able to add user to the group also. I created many group on server like Friends, Sports, College etc. But how can I retrieve the names of all group from server?

Using the below code I can retrieve all the user in the group.

```
public void getUserList() {

    String groupName="Friends"
    final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {

        ParseRelation relation = currentUser.getRelation(groupName);
        ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();

        try {
            Log.e("Size ", "Size " + query.count());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // query.whereEqualTo("username", null);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject r = objects.get(i);
                        String name = r.getString("username").toString();
                        Log.e("user name ", "===>" + name);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error : " + e.toString(), 1).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

In above screen-shot I need all the names like Friends, MYGroup and xyz using one query.
Please help me.

Comment: Hi Jagdish, How did you add user to group? any examples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all groups, you need to query the Group class (or whatever you have called it):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> groupList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (ParseObject group : groupList) {
                Log.d("group", "Group name: " + group.get("name");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It return size 0 in groupList Object.

Comment: For reference i attached the screen in the question.Could you please look on to this? Thanks!

Comment: Mate, you really need to study the parse docs, especially the Android Guide. Your screen makes no sense. "Friends", "MyGroup", "xyz" are not groups; they are classes. You need to create a Group class, and then store groups with names etc as objects in that class.

Comment: One more query.Is it possible chat using parse in android?Have you work any chat application for one to one,group chat? Please recommend me.I am working on by past week but not succeed.

Comment: Sure, this is possible. Check out this tutorial: http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com  It is for iOS, but the same principles can be used for Android. The functionality and API are more or less the same. If you study the Android Guide first, you should be able to port most of the tutorial over to Android. There are also other sources and libraries, like http://engineering.hipmob.com/2012/11/03/How-to-add-live-chat-to-your-Parse-powered-app-with-Hipmob/   Google for parse.com and chat :-)   Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for support.

Comment: @Handsomeguy  how to store data in specific table of parse from android